# How can I fix the origin of my repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, gitkraken

I have a problem with working on a git-repository I have with a group. We use GitKraken.
I cant really push anything I worked on, but I can pull the changes the others did.
I get this error:

[image]

And if I try to stage the files it's just on my local branch...I already tried delete the local branch and then I tried to stage my changes again but again it was just on my local branch.

[image]

I hope I can get it fixed soon.

(also sorry if I sound a little weird, I am not really used to git yet and english isnt my first language^^)

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to push on the remote branch?

Comment: I think you dont have the authorisation to push to this branch, try to change the access rights

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thank you.
It works now. I didnt had the right access rights for pushing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).